# Why is the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException not catching unhandled exceptions from non-UI threads?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've read some other threads and articles suggesting that there is a way to catch unhandled exceptions that originate on non-UI threads.  For some reason, this is not working for me.  Unhandled UI exceptions are being caught.  CurrentDomainUnhandledException never executes even when I test by throwing an exception from within a non-UI thread.

What's weirder is that the exception on the non-UI thread doesn't shut down the application as I thought it would.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += CurrentDispatcherUnhandledException;

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
               CurrentDomainUnhandledException;
    }

    void CurrentDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Caught an unhandled exception!");
    }

    void CurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Uncaught Thread Exception",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

I'm throwing from an event handler that handles devices being plugged in which is definitely not a UI thread. The debugger breaks and shows me a message that the exception is unhandled.  However when I continue the application keeps running and appears to keep working. I'm baffled by that.

```
_devicePlugWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(pluggedQueryStr);
_devicePlugWatcher.EventArrived += (DevicePluggedEventReceived);
```

Comment: Are you *sure* the message box isn't being shown?  It may be hiding in the background because of the debugger bringing Visual Studio into the foreground.  If you're sure, try using `Dispatcher.[Begin]Invoke` to open the message box on the UI thread.

Comment: I set a breakpoint within CurrentDomainUnhandledException and it is never hit. I see your point and if that code executed then I should probably implement that suggestion.  At the moment the handler never executes.

Comment: Are you sure the exception isn't being caught?  The debugger could be breaking on first chance exceptions, even if they are later caught.

Comment: You need to switch back to UI thread to have MessageBox displayed. There is no message loop in the worker threads thus no UI interaction. Use `CheckAccess' method to determine wherever you can show the message box or switch to UI thread.

Comment: @Mike, I don't know what you mean.  if I set a breakpoint in CurrentDomainUnhandledException then why wouldn't the debugger break there?

Comment: @shawn1874 I meant, maybe the exception isn't *actually* unhandled; maybe it's being caught on the thread where it is thrown.  Just because the debugger breaks and shows you an exception notification doesn't mean it's unhandled: the debugger might be configured to break on *any* exception at the time it's thrown, even if that exception is eventually handled.  And if it *is* being handled, the `UnhandledException` would not be raised.  Lastly, if the exception originates in a `Task`, you'll need to handle an additional event (see @mm8's answer for details).

Answer (score 5):

The `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event handler should be invoked if an exception is thrown on a non-thread pool thread (or non-`Task`). Try this for example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainUnhandledException;

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            throw new Exception("test");
        });
        thread.Start();
    }

    void CurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Uncaught Thread Exception",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

And compare it to this where the exception occurs inside a non-observed `Task`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception("test");
        });

        Loaded += (s, e) => 
        {
            //gc so the unobserved exception "bubbles" up
            GC.Collect(3, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
        };
    }

    private void TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = e.Exception;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Uncaught Thread Exception",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

So you should also handle `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`.

Comment: Ok.  I will try that and see what happens.  The exception in question was within a thread that I don't create.  The windows management events for devices indicating when a USB port is plugged or unplugged is where I was putting the exception as a test.  I can't figure out what type of thread that is.  I'll post back and accept the answer if that example works for me.  Thanks for posting some code.

Comment: Looking at the threads displayed by Visual Studio it appears that the System.Management.dll!System.Management.MTAHelper.WorkerThread is the thread that publishes the device plugged and unplugged events.  Therefore I don't believe that I need the TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException.  If I process a windows management event that a serial device is unplugged and I insert code to throw an unhandled exception the debugger will break and issue a message that it is unhandled.  However the CurrentDomainUnhandledException event handler does not execute.

Comment: Take a look at this git hub project for some code which shows how I am implementing the device detection.  https://github.com/Shawn1874/CodeSamples/tree/master/WpfSamples/DeviceDiscoverySample

Comment: Essentially adding that third exception handler didn't work for me. None are catching an unhandled exception from the System.Management.dll!System.Management.MTAHelper.WorkerThre‌​ad

Comment: >  non-thread pool thread

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` is raised for ThreadPool threads too.